# jQuery Replicate an existing Div Multiple Times

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, performance

I am building a search query which gives me results.

I have a template ready for the item inside a hidden div. What I want to do is replicate the template n number of times using jQuery.

So For example:
I search for flights and **I get 5 search results**, I need to **replicate the below div template** **5 Times**

```
<div id="oneWayFlightElement" class="displayNone">
        <div id="flightIndex1" class="flightDetailElement boxShadowTheme">
                <div id="flightDetailsLeftPanel1" class="flightDetailsLeftPanel marginBottom10">
                    <div class="fullWidth marginTop10">
                        <span id="flightPriceLabel1" class="headerFontStyle fullWidth boldFont">Rs 9500.00</span><hr/>
                           <div id="homeToDestination1" class="flightBlockStyle">
                            <span id="flightNumberFromHome1" class="fontSize16">AI-202</span><br/>
                               <span id="flightRouteFromHome1" class="fontSize26">PNQ > DEL</span><br/>
                               <span id="flightDepartTimeFromHome1" class="fontSize26">Depart: 10.00 AM</span><br/>
                               <span id="flightArrivalTimeFromHome1" class="fontSize26">Arrive: 12.00 PM</span><br/>
                           </div>
                           <div id="destinationToHome1" class="flightBlockStyle">
                            <span id="flightNumberToHome1" class="fontSize16">AI-202</span><br/>
                               <span id="flightRouteToHome1" class="fontSize26">PNQ > DEL</span><br/>
                               <span id="flightDepartTimeToHome1" class="fontSize26">Depart: 10.00 AM</span><br/>
                               <span id="flightArrivalTimeToHome1" class="fontSize26">Arrive: 12.00 PM</span><br/>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
                   <div id="flightDetailsRightPanel1" class="flightDetailsRightPanel textAlignRight marginBottom10">
                    <img src="images/flightIcon.png" class="marginRight10 marginTop10 width40"/><br/>
                       <button class="marginRight10 marginBottom10 width40 bookNowButtonStyle">Book Now</button>
                   </div>
                </div>
    </div>
```

Inside this div for 5 times

```
<div id="searchFlightResultDiv" class="fullWidth" style="border:solid">

                </div>
```

Is there a better way to do that rather than string appending in jQuery?

Thanks,
Ankit Tanna

Comment: Possibly try some templating framework?

Comment: @EvanKnowles I am avoiding using Templating Framework as I have an idea of templating using jQuery and JavaScript.

Comment: jquery has [.clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) , which you could use and then just change the text/values on the specific places using .text() or whatever.. ***or*** just make your one function that replicates the same template but takes arguments for the things that can change value/text

Comment: i would suggest at least using something like `ejs` http://www.embeddedjs.com/ to breakout the html from your js.. then you should be able to call the template multiple times and allow it to dynamically fill in values.. im particularly worried about all those `id`s you have and that they would NEED to be unique.. so something like `clone()` would be a worrying option unless you're also incrementing those `id`s dynamically too. (are they really ALL necessary?)

Comment: Sorry, its a strict restriction for using a framework just for templating purpose.

Answer (score 0):

```
function populateResult(resCount) {
    resCount = typeof resCount === 'number' ? resCount : 0;
    var res = [];
    var templateEle = $('#oneWayFlightElement');

    for(var i = 0; i < resCount; ++i)
        res.push(templateEle.clone().removeAttr('id class')[0]);

    $('#searchFlightResultDiv').html(res);
}

populateResult(5);
```

We use an array `res` to hold the DOM elements as we loop and finally sets it to the target div using `html` method. We don't need a JQuery object here as the `html` method accepts any array like object. In this way we can minimize browser reflows. Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rtfbzx0k/)

Comment: sadly, this didnt work. It gave me undefined when I consoled the HTML. :(

Comment: My mistake. I should have ran it before posting. Corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to wrap your template `div` (`#flightIndex1`) in a container with a unique `id` attribute. Then, you take the contents of that container (a template for a single record), and append it to your results `div` (`#searchFlightResultDiv`) using some type of loop based on the number of results received.

Basically,

**HTML**:

```
<!-- Here's your template -->
<div class="displayNone" id="oneWayFlightElement">
    <!-- This id (singleResult) is important -->
    <div id="singleResult">Result</div>
</div>
<!-- Container for the results -->
<div id="results"></div>
```

**Javascript**:

```
//Get the number of results. 
//This can be sent from your API or however you're getting the data.
//For example, in PHP you would set this to $query->num_rows();
var count = 5;

//Start a for loop to clone the template element (div#singleResult) into div#results 'count' times.
//This will repeat until the number of records (count) has been reached.
for (i = 1; i <= count; i++) {

    //Append the HTML from div#thingToRepeat into the #results.
    $('#results').append($('#singleResult').clone());

}
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/npw6m0su/6/) to show you how it works. You can play with it and tweak it if necessary.

I can't in good conscious complete this post without telling you the downsides of this. Doing it this way is *majorly* frowned upon in the web development community and is *super* inefficient. It may be good for practice and learning, but please do take a look at and consider a javascript templating framework like [moustache](http://mustache.github.io/) or [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/). It does this same thing but way more efficiently.

Hope this was helpful!

Comment: Appending will increase the DOM Reflow, which I want to avoid.

Comment: My [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/npw6m0su/7/) keeps reflows minimal. Hope it helps! And again, [templating frameworks](http://handlebarsjs.com/) are awesome!

Comment: I do understand that, but this is a string appending operation and unmuted variables are dangerous in JavaScript.